# Scrolling Issue in TextArea field in Android Webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have a hybrid app that has html elements displayed in a webview in Android. In those HTML elements I have a multi-line text view. Once I enter multiple lines in it, say number 1 to 20. I can't scroll it anymore. Below is the explanation of the scenario

```
4 |
5 
6 
7 
8 
9
```

In above scenario if my cursor is at 4 with 1,2,3 not visible and 10,11.... are not visible as well as they are out of text box. I can't scroll up. If i tap on 8 and cursor comes on 8. I can scroll upward then till 8 but not beyond.

I am facing this issue in Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 running on OS 4.3. Tested in multiple devices running on OS version 4.2.2. It works fine there.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
This my TextArea Tag :

```
<textarea Class="abc" role="textbox" maxlength="100" tabindex="-1" rows="6" style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto;" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Figured out the scrolling issue by adding
    -webkit-user-select: none;
But this made the TextArea as readable. I can scroll the elements inside it but can't edit anything nor I can add a new text. Even the cursor is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

Just override your textareafield. Using below code

```
Ext.define('MyApp.util.TextArea', {
   override: 'Ext.form.TextArea',
adjustHeight: Ext.Function.createBuffered(function(textarea) {
    var textAreaEl = textarea.getComponent().input;
    if (textAreaEl) {
        textAreaEl.dom.style.height = 'auto';
        textAreaEl.dom.style.height = textAreaEl.dom.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
}, 200, this),

constructor: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.on({
        scope: this,
        keyup: function(textarea) {
            textarea.adjustHeight(textarea);
        },
        change: function(textarea, newValue) {
            textarea.adjustHeight(textarea);
        } 
    });
}});
```